# How to share a directory from host to guest machine in VirtualBox

Tags: 18.04, mount, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox installed on Ubuntu 18.04 and within VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04 is also installed i.e. both host and guest machine are the same OS. Now I need to transfer some files from host machine to guest machine, I followed instructions mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders).

But while issuing the following command in guest machine

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host
```

I am getting an error

> mount: /home/atinesh/host: mount point does not exist

How can I transfer files from host machine to guest machine

**Update**:
I have created `home` directory in Guest OS, Now while Issuing the same command as mentioned above getting this error

> mount: /home/atinesh/host: wrong fs type, bad option, bad super block on share, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Comment: You didn't create `~/host`.

Comment: If it is about simple transferring files and not keeping the shared volume - what about the scp?

Comment: @Pilot6 I have updated the post please have a look

Comment: In guest OS try to run `sudo chmod 777 /home/atinesh/host` - Did you try the troubleshooting section of the document you referring to ?

Comment: The shared folder did not mount properly even after installing guest additions. After several hours of searching, I realized that I can simply drag/drop folders from Windows to Ubuntu - so the need for the shared folder is gone.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest to use VirtualBox Shared Folders.

Make sure that `Guest Additions` is installed in your VM.

In the `Shared Folder` setting for your VM... *ie: using my Desktop folder*...

[image]

**In your VM...**

In `terminal`...

`sudo adduser $USER vboxsf` # add user to vboxsf group

Log out, log in so that vboxsf is available.

Open a `Files` window and open the shared Desktop (*in my example*) folder. You may also see a sf_Desktop folder icon on the desktop.

Comment: Getting error while issuing command you mentioned `addUser: The group 'vboxsf' does not exist`

Comment: @Atinesh Make sure you're in the VM, and do the `sudo adduser $USER vboxsf`, and if that still fails, then try `sudo addgroup vboxsf` first, to add the missing group.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue by first adding my username to vboxsf

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
```

And then I still had to install this package to see the shared folder

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks. I can say the same solution works for Ubuntu 20.04.
1. sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
2. sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
3. log out / log in

Answer (score 0):

I also faced problem in sharing folders on ubuntu 18.04. I degraded the version and installed ubuntu 16.04. Problem got solved. No need to separately mount the folder. Just adding name to group vboxsf and then restart VM worked.

Comment: This is not a solution for Ubuntu 18.04 that you mentioned in here, you just started using a totally different version of Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

> I solved my issue by first adding my username to vboxsf
>
> > sudo adduser USER_NAME vboxsf And then I still had to install this package to see the shared folder
> >     sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils

almost worked, BUT although I wanted to be mounted at /mnt/mydir, as configured in virtualbox I ended up getting it mounted on /media/sf_mydir

Comment: If you disable automount (for the share via the Virtualbox Manager), you can mount the share wherever you want. On that note, automounting works great so I usually leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

1. On guest and Host machine both folder permission

   `chmod 777 /shared_dir_name`
2. On Guest machine:

   `sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils`

   `sudo adduser $USER vboxsf`
3. Now check on guest machine

   `df -h`